# Cannot load Ubuntu desktop after installing Nvidia driver

Tags: boot, nvidia, login

I've just installed an Nvidia driver for my Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit. Now I cannot load my desktop, the screen breaks after the login screen. The only thing that works is the console terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1). How can I fix this?

The Nvidia installer did say something about backing up the previous state of some X Server files. Perhaps if I could revert from this backup that would work but I cannot get to them.

Comment: "Perhaps if I could revert from this backup that would work but I cannot get to them." Those are in the same directory ending in ".old" if I remember correctly. (/etc/X11/ also holds a "xorg.conf.failsafe").

Comment: I don't know where they originally were. So are they in /etc/X11/ ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so (I checked but do not have a copy on my system here :D ). should be /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old)

Comment: There is no xorg.conf.old but there are several xorg.conf.something files there. Neither of them helped, not even the failsafe version.